# rar multiple files by php

Tags: php, rar

I am trying to rar multiple files by using exec() in php. (using rar command line)

sample code:

```
exec("rar a CommandOptionsHere File.rar File.txt");
```

The above code is to rar a single file, how do rar multiple files at one line of code?

Volumn split is possible at later stage.

Any advice?

P/S: i want to rar multiple files, not folder.

Comment: Note that really, this has nothing to do with PHP. Your question is essentially "how do I rar multiple files?" which has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
exec("rar a CommandOptionsHere File.rar File1.txt File2.txt");
```

see: http://pl.digipedia.org/man/doc/view/rar.1/